# How to setup a contact journey and add them in specific mailing group after a delay?

Tags: groups, smartgroups

I would like to setup a web signup form with 2 of our newsletter groups. After contacts sign up, I would like to send them 2 welcome emails after 10 days of delays. Then add them to the 1 of 2, or both newsletter whatever they have selected at the time of signup.

Setting up a form with groups, sending them welcome emails are an easy part using civirules.

I am struggling with how I can determine what group they were signed into at the beginning, so after 10 days of delay, they can go into that specific groups? I do not want to send them Newsletters before they receive the 2nd email. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if I totally understand but I have set up 2 journeys with CiviRules so I would like to understand to check if I can help you :-) So you have people signing up to group 1 OR group 2 and they all receive email1 right? And 10 days later email 2? And they should only receive the newsletter if they had email 2?

Comment: Also check out this extension: https://github.com/artfulrobot/chasse  I don't know whether it covers your needs but is on a similar topic.

Comment: @ErikH-CiviCooP Thanks for your reply. Say, contact A signs up for GROUP 1 Newsletter -  civirules sends Welcome EMAIL1 immediately after signup - after 10days  civirules sends EMAIL2 - Then contact A gets assigned to GROUP1. I do not want to send them GROUP1 Newsletters before they receive the EMAIL2.

Comment: OK, so you could remove them from the group immediately after email1 (with the same rule) and then re-add them after the second mail?

Comment: Thanks @ErikH-CiviCooP  but could you please clarify how I could remove them and re-add them automatically? Sorry I am not an expert.

Comment: @Aidan Thanks for the link. can "chasse" be linked to a subscription form?

Comment: In the CiviRule? With an action "remove contact from group"  and " add contact to group"? So in Rule 1, triggered by the contact being added to the group you send email1 AND remove them from the group immediately, and with a delay of 10 days send email 2 AND add them again to the group. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank! That did the job

Answer (score 2):

I would

1. Use webform(Drupal) or Caldera(Wordpress) for signup
2. Setup webform(Drupal) or Caldera(Wordpress) to create activity of type XXX as completed status with todays date on submission.
3. Setup Schedule reminder for Activity of type XXX

   a. 10 days after activity date

   b. 20 days after activity date
4. Setup 2 smart group

   a. Contacts having activity with activity datetime for past 10 days of type XXX

   b Contact having activity with type XXX and not in group 4.a

Cheers

Pradeep